# Is it possible to break a motor mount while doing transmission repairs?

Tags: transmission, motor-mounts

Long story short- took my vehicle in for transmission flush, they messed up and I’m now eating the cost of a new transmission. Now that they are repairing the transmission they say they notice the motor mount is broken. Is this something they could have accidentally broken while doing the transmission and torque converter repairs? I feel like this place has already screwed me once, just want to know if this is possible (could it have been broken or damaged during repairs) or if it is more likely already damaged before the repairs?

Comment: Could easily have been broken long before - when did you last check it? Or have it checked?

Comment: Difficult to prove as it could have been broken before but I suppose it may have been broken during a transmission/torque converter repair.  Why are you eating the cost of a new transmission if THEY messed up?

Comment: @Hwats Not a well worded question.  The title says "while doing transmission repairs...."   The content says "transmission flush".... No dealer or repair shop would be touching a transmission mount for a fluid flush. A "transmission repair" is something totally different.  Your inability to be clear in your communications here isn't helpful. The wording of your question seems disingenuous.  Possible to get you to clean up the question, be specific, be honest, while cleaning up your words?

Comment: @zipzit It reads fine to me.  A flush led to a fault.  The transmission and torque converter was removed and now a mount is faulty.  What is wrong with the question?   You need to read it properly this time.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this something they could have accidentally broken while doing the transmission and torque converter repairs?

Yes, it is possible.  To remove the transmission, they may have needed to pull the engine and transmission at an angle which could have damaged the engine mount.

It is also possible that it was already damaged and that the manoeuvre made it visible.

Comment: I'm confused. Why would a repair shop pull a transmission to perform a "transmission flush"?  Normally a flush requires hooking the vehicle up to a machine, sucking out the old fluid, replacing it with new fluid.  No need to remove the transmission.  No need to touch a transmission mount.  I will say, the title says "transmission repairs".  The content says "transmission flush".   Those could be two very different things.

Comment: @zipzit You are not reading the question correctly.  The flush was the original issue, then they pulled the transmission.  Now the mount is broken.  You are a bit too quick downvoting.

Comment: @zipzit "took my vehicle in for transmission flush, they messed up and I’m now eating the cost of a new transmission. Now that they are repairing the transmission they say they notice the motor mount is broken."